# File Access Denied

Tags: c#, file-io, permissions

I am using an FTPClient library to transfer files from a Windows share to an FTP server.

The SendFile method of the library uses the following code:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(localFileName, FileMode.Open);
```

This results in a System.UnauthorizedAccessException being thrown, however I am able to open, rename, and move the file using Windows Explorer under the same user account which the code is being executed.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

**Edit:**

The strange thing is that I can access other files on the share which have been granted the same NTFS permissions as the one that I can't.

This is also a Windows forms app.

**Update:**

Still no luck with this. I am able to read the file using a `StreamReader` but not a file stream. I can't understand why the two behave differently.

Comment: are you calling this from a 'windows forms' app, or an ASP.NET page?

Comment: from a windows forms app

Comment: any chance u are running the app from the share?  i know .net (by default) reduces the permissions of the app when u do that.

Comment: your file itself isn't read-only by any chance?

Answer (score 28):

Are you sure it's the same user account?
Can you try something like

```
MessageBox.Show(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
```

?

Also, are you sure the file isn't read-only? Do you need write access to the file?
Otherwise you could try:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(localFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  My file was read-only but since I wasn't requesting write access I assumed defining FileAccess.Read was unneeded.  I was wrong.  Adding FileAccess.Read was the key.

Answer (score 1):

The process that is running your code does not have permissions on the file.
Is it part of a web application - if so you need to give access to the ASPNET account.

Give permission to 'everyone' on the file, and see if it still has problems.

Answer (score 0):

1) NTFS permissions on the physical directory using explorer

2) Within the IIS MMC console FTP Site to allow read/write on the FTP folder

3) Ensure that the FTP Site or virtual directory actually exists, when checking the above step

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/inetserveriisftp/Jan2006/post25322215.asp

Comment: I believe the error is happening opening the file before it is sent?  i.e. FTP site permissions wouldn't be a factor at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Is your project being run from a network drive?  If so that that will mean it runs in a restricuted priviliges mode that could cause this.  Try copying the project to your C drive and running it again.

Comment: No i am running it in debug mode from within visual studio from the default local projects directory.

I am trying to access the file via it's UNC path e.g. \\server\share\file but aslong as I have the correct permissions (i have Full Access) that should not be a problem right?

Answer (score 0):

It's near FileSecurity class.

See at [FileSecurity class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity.aspx)

and try:

```
        // Get a FileSecurity object that represents the
        // current security settings.
        FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(localFileName);

        // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings.
        fSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("DOMAIN\USERNAME",
            FileSystemRights.ReadData, AccessControlType.Allow));

        // Set the new access settings.
        File.SetAccessControl(localFileName, fSecurity);
```

Comment: That results in: Unhandled Exception: System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException: Some
or all identity references could not be translated.

There are domain trusts involved in this setup e.g i am a member of a group in another domain which is granted access to this file, I wonder if that is having an impact on this.

Comment: Did you change "DOMAIN\USERNAME" string?

Comment: oops i did but forgot to escape the "\", it ran fine now but i am still unable to access the file.